# If value from dictionary is in dataframe, return specific corresponding key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am new to python and pandas so would love some guidance here!
Given a dictionary and a DataFrame I am trying to extract the specific corresponding key if the value from the dictionary exists in the DataFrame.

For example:

```
Input:
    dict = {'Happy': [1, 2], 'Sad': [3, 4, 5]}
    
    people = {'Name': ['John','Tom','Helen'],'Status': [3,2,5]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(people, columns = ['Name', 'Status'])


Expected Output:
output_dict = {'John': 'Happy', 'Tom': 'Happy', 'Helen': 'Sad'}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    for key, value in dict.items():
        for val in value:
            for row in df.itertuples():
                if row.status == val:
                    return {df['Name']:key}
```

However for some reason my dict at the end is always returned as empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try modify your `dict` , then with `replace` or `map`

```
out = df.set_index('Name').Status.replace({z : x for x , y in d.items() for z in y } ).to_dict()
{'John': 'Sad', 'Tom': 'Happy', 'Helen': 'Sad'}
```

Comment: Thanks BENY. As a quick follow up, how would I handle a situation where a dict has a non number ie:

    dict = {'Happy': [1, 2], 'Sad': [3, 4, 5], 'Unsure':['_']}